# Capistrano rbenv - Ruby version not installed witn dry run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, rbenv

When I run Capistrano task with dry run it tells me that rbenv Ruby version can't be found. I assume with dry run it should use local environment. But when I run the commands locally I can easily find below mentioned directory and Ruby is installed.

```
> ./bin/bundle exec cap --dry-run development t

DEBUG [8171d925] Running [ ! -d ~/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3 ] as user@dev
DEBUG [8171d925] Command: [ ! -d ~/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3 ]
ERROR rbenv: 2.4.3 is not installed or not found in ~/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3

> ls ~/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3
bin include lib share

> rbenv global
2.4.3

> ruby -v
ruby 2.4.3p205 (2017-12-14 revision 61247) [x86_64-darwin16]

> bundle info capistrano
* capistrano (3.4.0)
```

My Capfile contains below lines.

```rb
require 'capistrano/rbenv'
set :rbenv_type, :user
set :rbenv_ruby, '2.4.3'
```

I'm using Mac OS and installed rbenv with homebrew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must have been some bug in `capistrano/rbenv`. I have changed my Gemfile as follows and problem is solved.

```rb
# gem 'capistrano-rbenv', '2.0.2'
gem 'capistrano-rbenv', '~> 2.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your PATH and make sure it contains `$HOME/.rbenv/shims` and `$HOME/.rbenv/bin`

To view your path do:

`$ echo $PATH`

Also check that you have the following in your ~/.bash_profile

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

To check bash profile enter in terminal:

```
touch ~/.bash_profile; open ~/.bash_profile
```

Make sure it's the last setting in your ~/.bash_profile

Answer (score 0):

> I assume with dry run it should use local environment.

This is not true.

A Capistrano dry-run simply prints out the remote commands that it would run in an actual deploy, but it does execute them at all (local or otherwise).

Since Capistrano is not executing any commands, any plugins that rely on results of those commands may not work. For example, the rbenv plugin is apparently expecting to run this command:

```
[ ! -d ~/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3 ]
```

In a dry-run scenario, this is not actually executed. Instead, Capistrano just prints the command and continues as if the command succeeded.

In this particular case, for `[ ! -d ~/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3 ]` to "succeed" means that the  `~/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3` does not exist. The rbenv plugin thus prints an error an halts the deployment.

To summarize: in practice, the `--dry-run` option is not particularly useful.

Comment: By saying "local" I mean it doesn't connect anywhere - and after few tests I can confirm it's true. It might be as you say and that capistrano-rbenv behavior has been fixed. Either way, upgrading it to latest version does not produce any errors and completes fine, thus I can see all commands executed.